# Google Maps APK IP addresses

Tags: android, google-maps

We are developing a mobile application that calls Google Maps APK on the device for directions. WE are trying to test this on an emulator but our firewall is blocking it for self-signed certificates. Is there any way to get a list of IP addresses that Google Maps APK calls?

Comment: Are you referring to the native Google Maps app on Android or Google Maps Platform APIs?

Comment: The native app @jabamataro